# Infer type in factory class

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a DataHolder Class to manage point and lines information.
DataHolder has 2 children classes. Each children class manage one type of data (number, number[])

```
const enum DataType { POINT, LINE }

class DataHolder<T> {
    protected type: DataType;
    protected data: T[] = [];

    constructor(type: DataType) { this.type = type; }

    public add(data: T) { this.data.push(data); }

    public clear() { this.data.length = 0; }

    public static factory(type: DataType) {
        switch (type) {
            case DataType.POINT: return new PointHolder();
            case DataType.LINE: return new LineHolder();
            default: return undefined;
        }
    }
}
class PointHolder extends DataHolder<number> {
    constructor() { super(DataType.POINT); }
}
class LineHolder extends DataHolder<number[]> {
    constructor() { super(DataType.LINE); }
}
type holders = PointHolder | LineHolder;
```

Next, I have an overloaded functions to get and fill de dataHolders:

```
const holders = new Map<DataType, holders>();
const currentTypes: DataType[] = [];

function getDataHolder(type: DataType.POINT): PointHolder;
function getDataHolder(type: DataType.LINE): LineHolder;
function getDataHolder(type: DataType): holders {
    if (!holders.has(type)) {
        holders.set(type, DataHolder.factory(type));
        currentTypes.push(type);
    }
    return holders.get(type);
}

function add(type: DataType.POINT, ids: number): void;
function add(type: DataType.LINE, ids: number[]): void;
function add(type: DataType, ids: number | number[]): void {
    let hldr: holders;
    switch (type) {
        case DataType.POINT:
            hldr = getDataHolder(type);
            hldr.add(ids);      // Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
            break;
        case DataType.LINE: {
            hldr = getDataHolder(type);
            hldr.add(ids);      // Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
function clear() {
    for (const type of currentTypes) {
        const hldr = getDataHolder(type); // No overload matches this call
        hldr.clear();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to define the overloaded functions "getDataHolder" andd "add" to infer the corrects types of the passed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

typescript has some weird behavior when it comes to union types

add function:
typescript cannot infer type base on another argument. but it can infer properties of an object so you can write it as

```
interface pointParams {
    type: DataType.POINT; ids: number;
}

interface lineParams {
    type: DataType.LINE; ids: number[];
}

type addFunc = (para: pointParams | lineParams) => void

let add:addFunc = function(para) {
    let hldr: holders;
    switch (para.type) {
        case DataType.POINT:
            hldr = getDataHolder(para.type);
            hldr.add(para.ids);      // Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
            break;
        case DataType.LINE: {
            hldr = getDataHolder(para.type);
            hldr.add(para.ids);      // Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

clear function: this one is also kinda weird typescript know `DataType == DataType.POINT | DataType.LINE`, but it doesn't know `DataType.POINT | DataType.LINE == DataType`, so you have to declare getDataHolder to let it work

```
function getDataHolder(type: DataType.POINT): PointHolder;
function getDataHolder(type: DataType.LINE): LineHolder;
function getDataHolder(type: DataType): holders;
function getDataHolder(type: DataType): holders {
    if (!holders.has(type)) {
        holders.set(type, DataHolder.factory(type));
        currentTypes.push(type);
    }
    return holders.get(type);
}
```